# Open multiple terminal windows mac using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, unix

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/python

read -p "Execute script:(y/n) " response
if [ "$response" = "y" ]; then
    echo -e "\n\nLoading....\n\n"

    for ((x = 0; x<5; x++))
    do
        echo -e "Open $x terminal\n\n"
        open -a Terminal.app
    done
fi
```

This only opens a single new terminal window. How can I open 10 new terminal windows?

Comment: I think you can only have one shebang (`#!`) per file, so your `#!/usr/bin/python` is unnecessary / ignored.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open 10 new Terminal windows from a bash script (or from the command line), use the following command:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'repeat 10 times' -e 'do script ""' -e 'end repeat' -e 'end tell'
```

---

Or integrated into your existing code, albeit re-coded:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nocasematch
read -p " Execute script? (y/n): " response
if [[ $response == y ]]; then
    printf " Loading....\\n"
    for ((x = 0; x<10; x++)); do
        printf " Open %s Terminal\\n" $x
        osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script ""' >/dev/null
    done
fi
shopt -u nocasematch
```

---

Its output would be:

```
$ ./codetest
 Execute script? (y/n): y
 Loading....
 Open 0 Terminal
 Open 1 Terminal
 Open 2 Terminal
 Open 3 Terminal
 Open 4 Terminal
 Open 5 Terminal
 Open 6 Terminal
 Open 7 Terminal
 Open 8 Terminal
 Open 9 Terminal
$
```

With 10 new Terminal windows showing, assuming you've not set to have new windows open in tabs.

Comment: Or, to integrate closer to the code in question: `for ((x=0; x<5; x++)) ; do osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "" ' ; done`

Comment: @Asmus, Didn't see you comment when posted and only saw it now because someone upvoted the answer; however, the OP stated "How can I open 10 new terminal windows?" and why I used `x<10` instead of `1x<5` as in his code, so using  `1x<5` or integrating closer is not what the OP wanted. 10 is what's wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the -n option to the open command

`-n`  Open a new instance of the application(s) even if one is already running.

```
for ((x = 0; x<5; x++)) do
    echo -e "Open $x terminal\n\n"
    open -na Terminal.app
done
```

Comment: open -an Terminal.app gives "Cannot find file" error

Comment: Sorry I mixed up the option order. Should be n first then a

Comment: Note that this opens additional _instances_ of Terminal.app, not additional _windows_ within one app. The latter should be preferred, I think.